# How do we create N matrices simultaneously in C++?

Tags: c++

I would like to create `N` matrices of dimension `(n,k)` simultaneously.

I have a code in Matlab and I am trying to convert it to C. Lets say that I want to construct 2 matrices simultaneously, in R language is the following:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-an-array-in-r.html ("See please the paragraph **"Use the creator functions in R")**

Please help me, I know that for some of you this question is silly but I' m new to this language and I have no one else to ask.

Comment: Define *simultaneously*. Or you simply need 3 such matrices?

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector` or `std::array` than C-array.

Comment: Read http://rajkishor09.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-work-with-Multidimensional-Array-in-C-Programming and specifically 3D array is what you are looing at

Comment: @Kedar I read it and it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets first explain something about multi dimension arrays. `a[n][k]` is n arrays, each one k elements long. So,  `a[n][k][N]` will create n arrays of type `a[k][N]`. All you need to do is define the array (for example: `int a[2][3][4]`).

If you don't know the sizes of the arrays in compile time, use dynamic allocation and pointers. The code is something like this:

```
int*** pppA = new int**[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    pppA[i] = new int*[k];
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        pppA[i][j] = new int[N];
    }
}
```

don't forget to delete the memory ofter you finished using it.

I don't know R, but if I understood the example linked in the comment, what you are looking for is something like that (if you know the dimensions in compile time):

```
int a[3][4][2];
```

this will create a array of integers, with no initialize values. If you want to initialize it, you have two options - writing a loop or using a initializer.

initializer:

```
int a[2][4][3] = {{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}},{{13,14,15},{16,17,18},{19,20,21},{22,23,24}}};
//print the array
for (int i =0; i < 2; i ++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            cout << a[i][j][k] << ','; 
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
}
```

loop:

```
int a[2][4][3];
for (int i =0; i < 2; i ++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            a[i][j][k] = 12 * i + 4*j + k; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to look at those first couple of sentences again. If `a[n][k]` is `n` arrays of `k` elements, then `a[n][k][N]` is `n` arrays of dimension `array[k][N]`. You present one case where your first dimension is the number of arrays, then a second case where your last dimension is the number of arrays, which is inconsistent. In reality, either is just a single array (memory addresses are sequential after all), and the compiler simply remembers the dimensions so that it can calculate proper offsets when you reference elements of the array...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know this language well and I am not able to understand your post. Could you please tell me how could I do this example http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-an-array-in-r.html (see please the paragraph "Use the creator functions in R") with C?

Comment: @twalberg yes, but it helps to think about this this way for two reasons: a. the compiler does define a type for each dimension. b. When you allocate dynamically that's what you get.